# Earnings statistics report per asset

Tags: youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

Is there any way to get statistics earnings per ASSET report over API ? 
I'm able to get earnings per video but not per asset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `asset` dimension instead of `video`. It's not mentioned on Youtube Analytics documentation, but it work fine.

Comment: This is no longer possible, that query just returns 400